# Proxy to an object, proper const qualification and lack thereof

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, constants, c++14

I just found something that looks like a quirk to me. Consider :

```
struct Tile {

    Tile(Map &map, int, int)
    : map(map) { }

    void destroy();

    void display() const;

    Map &map;
};
```

This (stripped down) class is an accessor object. It's constructed by the `Map` itself as such :

```
Tile Map::operator ()(int x, int y) {
    return Tile(*this, x, y);
}

Tile const Map::operator ()(int x, int y) const {
    return Tile(*this, x, y);
}
```

So a `Map` can return a `Tile` from which we can call `destroy()` (which updates the map), and a `Map const` can only return a `Tile const`, from which we can only call the non-modifying `display()` method.

So everything's good, right ? Well, not quite. Because even though it seemed pretty straightforward at first, I can't figure out how to construct a Tile from a `Map const`, because of the `Map&` constructor parameter.

I also tried removing `Tile`'s constructor and aggregate-initializing it, to no avail :

```
Tile const Map::operator ()(int x, int y) const {
    return { *this, x, y };
}
```

... which looks even stranger to me, since I get an...

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘Map&’ from expression of type ‘const Map’
```

... even though a `Tile const` should only contain `const` fields, shouldn't it ?

Why does the compiler complain on that last one (the first is quite logical), and can I do something short of rewriting the whole Tile class specifically for `const` access ? Could it be one of the mythical places where `const_cast` is right ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A solution is to make two classes `Tile` and `ConstTile`. This is similar to the `iterator`/`const_iterator` story. Note that there are ways for the two classes may share some implementation if necessary.

Comment: If your design calls for `Map &` to be initialized from a `const Map` then you need to re-think your design.  The only syntax for doing that is to use `const_cast` which, as you say, is a sign that you've made a mess somewhere.

Comment: I somehow missed the similarity with iterators, but it's indeed the exact same problem. Well, in my case it's not *that* bad, but wouldn't it be wonderful if it just worked. @MattMcNabb: That rings like a stock answer :p I honestly think proxy objects fit in my case, the only problem I have is implementing their innards. Note that the `Map` reference isn't going to remain `public` for long.

Comment: A possible hack if you don't want separate `Tile` and `constTile` classes is to store `Map const &` plus a `bool` indicating whether it's safe to cast away the const

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daniel's on the right track - you definitely need a `Tile` and `ConstTile` class, which can be templated for simplicity, but you need to deal with when you can call `destroy()` and how you can construct them. To that end:

```
template<class MapT>
struct TileT {

    TileT(MapT &map, int, int)
    : map(map) { }

    // we want to be able to construct ConstTile from Tile
    template <typename M>
    TileT(const TileT<M>& tile)
    : map(tile.map) { } 

    void destroy() {
        static_assert(!std::is_const<MapT>::value, "Cannot call destory() from ConstTile");
        // rest of implementation
    }

    void display() const;

    MapT &map;
};

using Tile = TileT<Map>;
using ConstTile = TileT<const Map>;
```

That will give you the desired functionality and will work in a similar fashion to how `iterator`/`const_iterator` work. So you can do stuff like:

```
Map map;
...
ConstTile tile = map(4,3); // non-const map, ConstTile is ok
```

Comment: Oh, that's where you meant to place the static_cast ! Seems clearer now. So the `static_assert` doesn't fire until the user tries to call the method ? Edit : please disregard my previous comment, I messed up.

Comment: @Quentin The `static_assert` will prevent the call from compiling.

Comment: @Quentin Really it's only there to make explicit why things fail. Without it, if you try to call `map.some_non_const_func()`, that will fail to compile anyway, because of an error about the `const` qualifier.

Comment: I just tried it on g++-4.9.1, and the assertion fires without me calling the function :/

Comment: Wait, that's another problem altogether. It actually works with `std::is_const`. But I was unsure about `static_assert`'s behaviour inside methods, so I gave it a try with a `static_assert(false,"")` in the same place... Which blew up. I'm clueless. Edit: [here's the code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0153001fab2ca53)

Comment: @Quentin That's because the condition `false` doesn't depend on any of the template parameters. Change it to something that depends on `MapT` and it will either fail or not fail only if you call `dontCallMe()`.

Comment: Why introduce `M` in that copy constructor? Why not reuse `MapT`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So I can construct a `TileT<const Map>` from a `TileT<Map>`.

Comment: I have trouble understanding why it is that way (it's not SFINAE this time, is it), but that will be for another day. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I see no way around creating two versions of the Tile class: One for const access and one for mutable access. Consider the following: What should the destroy function do, if the Map reference is const?

If you want to get around making a Tile and a ConstTile version of the class, you can use templates to achieve the same effect and still avoid code duplication.

```
template<class MapT>
struct Tile {

    Tile(MapT &map, int, int)
    : map(map) { }

    template<typename U = MapT>
    std::enable_if<std::is_const<U>::value> destroy();

    void display() const;

    MapT &map;
};
```

MapT can now be Map or const Map depending on the instantiation.

Comment: You cannot use `enable_if` like that.

Comment: I was actually thinking about such a template. About the `destroy()` function : it is simply not callable on a `Tile const`. That's what strikes me : the language seems all well-made about transferring constness, except for that one missing link. I will accept your answer if no revelation appears :)

Comment: @Barry fixed it. Too much template metaprogramming gets on the nerves ;)

Comment: @Quentin No you didn't. SFINAE doesn't apply in this context - `MapT` isn't a template for `destroy()`.

Comment: @Barry indeed, my nerves were also gotten on. The next sane thing to try is to conditionally inherit the non-`const` methods from a detail class, right ?

Comment: Is it good enough for your use case to just `static_assert(!std::is_const<MapT>::value)`?

Comment: @Barry That's back to square one, with a template and a `static_assert` on top :p

Comment: @Barry thanks for clearing that up! I edited my response in a new attempt to make it work. (seems to compile fine with g++) This is getting kind of ugly though. Maybe it is better to avoid meta programming magic for such a seemingly simple problem.